# AWS:Having issue with the VPC peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I was trying to do the VPC peering. Below is the diagram.

[image]

There are 3 VPC(A,B,C). The ip are 172.16.32.0/19, 172.16.96.0/19 and 172.17.32.0/19. I have internal load balances on VPC C and B. So I was trying to do VPC peering between A and C, A and B. VPC A and VPC C peering is working and I can access app inside C via A but can't do the same with VPC B. I have added both the ip's in routing table.

could someone point me to the right direction, what could be the issue as one peering is working but not the other.

Comment: Have you checked your security groups on VPC B applications? Also check the DNS setting on the VPC peerings, or both the same?

Comment: I don't *think* there is an documented limitation with a direct correlation to the problem you are seeing, but you need to be aware that 172.15.x.x is not within the scope of RFC-1918 private addresses, which only includes 172.16.0.0 through 172.31.255.255 (in addition to 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x, of course).  As a matter of best practice, though, I would suggest that you definitely should not use non-RFC-1918 address blocks inside a VPC without a thorough understanding of possible implications, not all of which are necessarily documented.